# Toolbar does not appear in VLC ActiveX

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vlc, windows

I am using the VideoLAN VLC ActiveX Plugin 2 (available from the VLC 1.1.11 installation) in my C#.NET Windows App.

**My Problem Is :**

The controller toolbar (seek bar, control buttons, volume) does not appear at all. Even after playing a file. Also it seems like the "Toolbar" property cannot be set to true, and is read-only?

**So my questions are:**

Is the "Toolbar" property a useless thing or is there a another way to set it to true?

Will the Toolbar appear at all after setting it to true, or would I have to implement it myself?

If I have to make a custom seek slider with control buttons, what are the API calls I can use to control media playback and seek-to-frame? VB.NET?

Is there any other way I can get the VLC player to show its Toolbar in my App?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the version two of the ActiveX control for VLC is intended to web browsers though it also works on winforms. That's why your toolbar isn't being displayed. Just tested in a chrome window the following code and the tool bar appeared ok:

```
<html>
<head><title>Demo of VLC mozilla plugin</title></head>

<body>

<embed 
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
    pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
    width="640"
    height="480"
    id="vlc"
    autoplay="true"
    src="file:///C:/test.avi"
/>
<object 
    classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" 
    codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab">
</object>


</body>
```

You can seek the stream through:
vlc.input.time: the absolute position in time given in milliseconds, this property can be used to seek through the stream

The documentation for the control can be found in http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin

You can consider adding the libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll directly to your app and interop with them. One good tutorial on this is:

http://www.helyar.net/2009/libvlc-media-player-in-c-part-2/